# How to extract the nth component of a path?

Tags: python

Consider the following file path:

```
path = r'C:\this\is\a\test_test\file.asc'
```

How can I extract the nth component of the path?

```
"test_test"
```

*without* slicing

```
path[13:22]
```

Comment: I think I'd go for a solution based on repeated calls to `os.path.split()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split()` as follows:

```
>>> path = r'C:\this\is\a\test_test\file.asc'
>>> path = path.split('\\')
>>> print path[4]
test_test
```

You need to use `'\\'` instead of `'\'` since you need to escape the backslash. Otherwise, you will end up escaping the second `'` and get an EOL parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

Split the path with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> path = r'C:\this\is\a\test_test\file.asc'
>>> path.split("\\") # Make sure you double the \
['C:', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test_test', 'file.asc']
>>> path.split("\\")[4]
'test_test'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ,

```
>>a=r'C:\this\is\a\test_test\file.asc'
>>a=a.split("\\")
>>print a[4]
```

Output:

```
'test_test'
```